# share a link on linkedin by api in php

Tags: api

I am developing an application, where I have to share link on social media. I got working on facebook, twitter and google, But could not found how to share a link on linkedin. 
My facebook url is like

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://mysite/ad-24.html
```

Is there any way api or tool to share post on linkedin site.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party but here's how you can do right now.

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=https://stackoverflow.com
```

More info at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin
and go to **Customized URL** tab.